# Running migrations on a server with exrm in Elixir

Tags: migration, elixir, phoenix-framework

I need to run the migrations on a server where I've deployed my Phoenix app by exrm. According to this http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2016/04/running-migration-in-an-exrm-release/  I've created first the 1st file for a migration and ran it:

```
$ rel/my_app/bin/my_app test1 Elixir.Release.Tasks migrateUsing ....../rel/my_app/releases/0.0.2/my_app.sh
Usage: my_app {start|start_boot <file>|foreground|stop|restart|reboot|ping|rpc <m> <f> [<a>]|console|console_clean|console_boot <file>|attach|remote_console|upgrade|escript|command <m> <f> <args>}
```

Then I decided to try the 2nd approach, created the 2nd file and ran it:

```
$ rel/my_app/bin/my_app command release_tasks  test2 
Using ......./rel/my_app/releases/0.0.2/my_app.sh
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{release_tasks,test2,[],[]},{init,start_it,1,[]},{init,start_em,1,[]}]}}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

What's wrong with that?

My files are at `priv/tasks.exs`

Answer (score 0):

`priv` directory is not in the load path. Move the `tasks.exs` to `lib/tasks.ex` and it should work.

Comment: Please post your tasks.ex file.

Comment: it's the same as in the article.

Comment: In the article they use `migrate` functions and you are using `test2`. If its exactly the same use `rel/my_app/bin/my_app command release_tasks migrate`.